# How to implement collapsing Toolbar with fragments and NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have an application with Activity, Fragment inside activity, Toolbar and Navigation Drawer.

I need a Toolbar will hiding when I scroll content of fragment.

Following [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) I need to put ToolBar and scrollable content inside same XML file. But my scrollable content placed in Fragment and ToolBar placed in Activity. How to implement collapsing Toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

Try to use this [guide](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/). There's good explanation